# Azure DevOps permissions change for users API?

Tags: security, azure-devops, permissions, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there an API for editing/adding users/user groups to a project's security groups in Azure DevOps? For example, create a new security group under project and add members under it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

Comment: May I know that how's the issue going now? Does below approach can get you unblock. Feel free to leave comment if you have any puzzle here.

Comment: This is great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Create a group and add members under this new group are separate steps. As of now, we have not provide one api that you can achieve them at once.*

---

(1) To [create a **new user group**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#create-a-group-at-the-project-level) under project level:

```
POST https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/groups?scopeDescriptor={scopeDescriptor}&api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

Request body:

```
{
  "displayName": "{group name}",
  "description": "{The description of this group}"
}
```

***Notes:***

- The only trouble here is getting **scopeDescriptor** of the project.
  Since you are trying to add group under **Project level**,
  **scopeDescriptor** is a necessary parameter of this api.

  **a.** Please firstly use this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to retrieve the id of the project that you would like to add the group to.

  ```
  GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0
  ```

  **b.** Then calling this [Descriptors - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/descriptors/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) api to get the corresponding **scopeDescriptor**.

  ```
  GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/descriptors/{storageKey}?api-version=5.0-preview.1
  ```

  Please replace **storageKey** with **project Id** since we need to
  get the scope descriptor for a project. The content of **Value**
  property is what we are looking for:

  [image]
- Please copy the **"descriptor"** value into a txt file from the response body after you create a new group successfully, it is the important parameter for next steps.

---

(2) Adding a member into this new group, please refer to this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#add-an-aad-user-as-member-of-a-group):

```
POST https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/users?groupDescriptors={xxxxx}&api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

Request body:

```
{
  "principalName": "{user' account address}"
}
```

**Notes:**

Here please input the **descriptor** value you copied from previous api's response body, as the value of `groupDescriptors` parameter.

For request body, just input the user's account address is ok.

Comment: Hi for set permission to team or group in azure devops for example pulll request permission can use api??